# I want to kill activities as soon as the user leaves it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an application(3d game) and use 4 activities for The splash page and introduction.

When the game starts, the other activities don't kill themselves. I am testing this with real and virtual devices. I know that the android system reclaims memory when it needs to do so, and my app works for all devices and screen sizes, except devices with low memory, it seems that they have enough memory to run the game without those extra-memory-usages, because android reclaims memory only from Kitkat, devices that run jellybean soon get clogged and crash.

Is there any way to end my activities as soon as the user leaves it? This is one of my splash pages, they use a timer to move to the next activity.

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

    public void onFinish() { 
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(activity1.this,activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent1); 
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout); 
        finish(); 
    }
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: As soon as you send the intent to next activity, call finish(); in the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

- FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
- FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
- FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
- FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

example (Finish all previous activities)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

It will totally clears all previous activity(s) and start new activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void goTo(Activity from, Class<?> to) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(from, to);
    if (from != null)
    {
        from.startActivity(intent);
        from.finish();  //**This will do**
    }
}
```

for your case, you should call **activity1.finish();**

Answer (score 0):

Activity is a Java object. In Java you don't remove objects by yourself, garbage collector does it for you. So you can't remove Activity from memory manually, but you can do few things that will help to garbage collector to remove the activity:

1. Make sure you don't save any links to your activity object after moving to other activity
2. Call finish() - as you do on your code example.

Thats it, garbage collector will remove activity from the memory when needed.

P.S I don't think your memory problems caused by not removing activities from the memory. Take a look at other abilities to optimize memory usage i.e you can use smaller or less quality images/models for devices with low memory.